# Finding the three top tags

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, reduce, map-function

This is going to be a bit lengthy, but I'm looking for help as to how to tackle/think through this. I want to get into the habit of thinking critically with this problem, but I've hit a wall. So any tricks/tips/advice are appreciated.

So I have an array of multiple objects like so (one of 8):

```
[{
  "_id": "555e4125afb26872ac1cb814",
  "index": 0,
  "guid": "e7bd5b56-43d3-41cb-9742-aee4408a36c2",
  "isActive": false,
  "balance": "$3,868.37",
  "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 37,
  "eyeColor": "brown",
  "name": "Adele Mullen",
  "gender": "female",
  "company": "GAPTEC",
  "email": "adelemullen@gaptec.com",
  "phone": "+1 (860) 572-3603",
  "address": "775 Tapscott Street, Mammoth, South Dakota, 9956",
  "about": "Aliqua duis ex id excepteur duis aute non ipsum laborum. Duis exercitation aliquip sint irure consectetur ex enim veniam irure aliquip ipsum dolore cillum sunt. Ea dolor magna cupidatat sint laboris ipsum. Cillum quis nisi laboris officia consequat nulla dolor adipisicing eu. Quis ut nostrud non aliqua.\r\n",
  "registered": "2014-05-12T22:50:11 +05:00",
  "latitude": 30.620088,
  "longitude": -156.753814,
  "tags": ["cupidatat", "do", "irure", "proident", "sit", "nulla", "aute"],
  "friends": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Justice Lara"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Duke Patrick"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Herring Hull"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Johnnie Berg"
  }],
  "greeting": "Hello, Adele Mullen! You have 8 unread messages.",
  "favoriteFruit": "banana"
}
```

My goal is to create a function  finding the three most common tags among all object's associated tags. My input and output will be an array, and I have recreated three HOF to work with objects to assist me in this process:

recreation of reduce:

```
function reduce(array, func, seed) {
var theArray = array;
var previousResult;
var i = 0;
if (seed !== null && seed !== undefined) {
    previousResult = seed;
} else {
    previousResult = array[0];
    theArray = array.slice(1, array.length);
    i =1;
}
each(theArray, function(value, index, collection) {
    previousResult = func(previousResult, value, index + i);
});
return previousResult;
```

recreation of map:

```
function map (collection, func) {
    var newArray = [];
    each(collection, function(value, index, collection) {
       newArray.push(func(value,index, collection)); 
    }); 
    return newArray;

 }
```

recreation of filter

```
function filter (collection, test) {
    const filtered = [];
    each(collection, function(value, position, collection) {
    if (test(value,position, collection)) 
         filtered.push(value); 
    }); 
    return filtered;
}
```

My main issues is how to advance with this problem given that I am most likely going to use these functions in a chain function reaction.

```
var topThreeTags = function(customers) {
var topThree = [];
var allTags = [];

_.map(customers, func(customer.tags) {
  topThree.push(customer.tags);
}
_.filter(allTags, function(value, curr, collection) {
      if (test(value.tags === curr[tag])) {
          topThree.push(curr);
      }
  }

};

return topThree;
};
```

I know this is incomplete code, but I've hit a road block and I want to get some clarity of where did I detour wrong and what I need to to to fix it.

Comment: By top 3 tags, do you mean those tags which have featured most in the objects?

Comment: I would be choosing this rount .. loop whole collection and count total of each tag,, then sort it, and return top 3 most items

Comment: Yes, by top three I mean most featured in the objects

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach

- **Map** the `tag`s with *count of their usage*

i.e.

```
var tagMap = {};
arr.forEach( function( item ){
   item.tags.forEach( function( tag ){
      tagMap[ tag ] = ( tagMap[ tag ] || 0 ) + 1;
   })
});
```

***Explanation***

**==** *Iterate all objects* in the array `arr`

**==** For every `item` in the object, *iterate its tags*.

**==** For every tag in the tags' array *initialize its count* to 0 (if it doesn't exist in the `map`) and *increment the same*.

After this step, you will have a map

> ```
> map = { 
>   "tag1" : 2, //2 is the count value
>   "tag3" : 3
> }
> ```

- **Convert to Array** of tags

Sort in the ascending order of count of occurrences

```
var sortedArr = Object.keys( tagMap ).map( s => [ s , tagMap[s] ] ).sort( (a,b) => a[1] - b[1] );
```

***Explanation***

**==** Get all keys of `map` in an array using `Object.keys(map)`

**==** Map all the keys into **another array** such that each item is `[ tag, count ]`

**==** Sort this array by count value

After this step, you will have a sorted array such as

> ```
> sortedArr = [
>   [ "tag3" , 3 ],
>   [ "tag4" , 2 ],
>   [ "tag2" , 2 ],
>   [ "tag1" , 1 ],
> ]
> ```

- **Slice** the top three values

i.e.

```
var output = sortedArr.slice(-3);
```

**Demo**

```js
var customers = [{
  "_id": "555e4125afb26872ac1cb814",
  "index": 0,
  "guid": "e7bd5b56-43d3-41cb-9742-aee4408a36c2",
  "isActive": false,
  "balance": "$3,868.37",
  "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 37,
  "eyeColor": "brown",
  "name": "Adele Mullen",
  "gender": "female",
  "company": "GAPTEC",
  "email": "adelemullen@gaptec.com",
  "phone": "+1 (860) 572-3603",
  "address": "775 Tapscott Street, Mammoth, South Dakota, 9956",
  "about": "Aliqua duis ex id excepteur duis aute non ipsum laborum. Duis exercitation aliquip sint irure consectetur ex enim veniam irure aliquip ipsum dolore cillum sunt. Ea dolor magna cupidatat sint laboris ipsum. Cillum quis nisi laboris officia consequat nulla dolor adipisicing eu. Quis ut nostrud non aliqua.\r\n",
  "registered": "2014-05-12T22:50:11 +05:00",
  "latitude": 30.620088,
  "longitude": -156.753814,
  "tags": ["cupidatat", "do", "irure", "proident", "sit", "nulla", "aute"],
  "friends": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Justice Lara"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Duke Patrick"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Herring Hull"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Johnnie Berg"
  }],
  "greeting": "Hello, Adele Mullen! You have 8 unread messages.",
  "favoriteFruit": "banana"
}, {
  "_id": "555e4125030944f697e16ab7",
  "index": 1,
  "guid": "eb2bd6bb-d032-4ec1-9e45-8d34535f8cf4",
  "isActive": true,
  "balance": "$3,690.70",
  "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 26,
  "eyeColor": "green",
  "name": "Olga Newton",
  "gender": "female",
  "company": "INTERGEEK",
  "email": "olganewton@intergeek.com",
  "phone": "+1 (856) 522-3065",
  "address": "428 Division Avenue, Morriston, Illinois, 5540",
  "about": "Incididunt cupidatat incididunt aliquip ea voluptate nisi Lorem. Consectetur consectetur sunt laborum ad sit pariatur velit pariatur quis. Quis veniam ex eiusmod aute ex cupidatat id sunt. Eiusmod minim enim sit duis ipsum enim culpa id eu dolore consectetur. Laborum ex magna deserunt ullamco cillum nisi culpa dolore ullamco incididunt ut. Non incididunt culpa pariatur id deserunt deserunt amet excepteur consectetur nostrud. Elit sint sit reprehenderit minim ex id anim et nulla cupidatat ex.\r\n",
  "registered": "2014-11-24T23:10:56 +06:00",
  "latitude": -36.350505,
  "longitude": -173.287501,
  "tags": ["voluptate", "non", "amet", "do", "occaecat", "commodo", "in"],
  "friends": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Cross Barnett"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Raquel Haney"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Cassandra Martin"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Shelly Walton"
  }],
  "greeting": "Hello, Olga Newton! You have 7 unread messages.",
  "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
}, {
  "_id": "555e41251beb2fc79cbafff7",
  "index": 2,
  "guid": "3bfda455-d93f-4e70-9632-21504df89ede",
  "isActive": true,
  "balance": "$1,005.44",
  "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 35,
  "eyeColor": "blue",
  "name": "Shelly Walton",
  "gender": "female",
  "company": "TYPHONICA",
  "email": "shellywalton@typhonica.com",
  "phone": "+1 (806) 578-2712",
  "address": "934 Elm Avenue, Sidman, Utah, 1267",
  "about": "Irure labore ut officia veniam ad tempor labore. Eu ullamco elit magna veniam. Deserunt excepteur ullamco eiusmod nisi magna dolor sint minim occaecat. Consequat dolore consequat culpa excepteur non Lorem ut. Occaecat excepteur eiusmod dolor labore.\r\n",
  "registered": "2014-11-15T07:22:23 +06:00",
  "latitude": 70.637542,
  "longitude": 38.023956,
  "tags": ["laborum", "esse", "occaecat", "id", "ea", "non"],
  "friends": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Cheryl Kent"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Greta Wells"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Gutierrez Waters"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Cooley Jimenez"
  }],
  "greeting": "Hello, Shelly Walton! You have 3 unread messages.",
  "favoriteFruit": "banana"
}, {
  "_id": "555e41253d951ad8d2d27b50",
  "index": 3,
  "guid": "ee28c73c-5692-4dba-96ba-3b695eb7122a",
  "isActive": true,
  "balance": "$2,491.36",
  "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 24,
  "eyeColor": "blue",
  "name": "Serena Odonnell",
  "gender": "female",
  "company": "ECOLIGHT",
  "email": "serenaodonnell@ecolight.com",
  "phone": "+1 (844) 559-3964",
  "address": "375 Beaver Street, Garfield, Maryland, 8966",
  "about": "Eu labore dolor ea reprehenderit duis laboris minim voluptate exercitation magna velit sunt. Proident adipisicing enim ut cupidatat. Irure ut tempor ea officia labore aliqua sint labore ipsum adipisicing magna aute. Deserunt voluptate aute minim ea nulla duis mollit anim.\r\n",
  "registered": "2014-12-03T08:18:32 +06:00",
  "latitude": 86.286967,
  "longitude": -98.561972,
  "tags": ["sint", "Lorem", "aliqua", "magna", "exercitation", "labore", "eu"],
  "friends": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Deborah Carr"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Stein Simpson"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Stefanie Leblanc"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Tsing Tao"
  }],
  "greeting": "Hello, Serena Odonnell! You have 1 unread messages.",
  "favoriteFruit": "apple"
}, {
  "_id": "555e412508a72c3ba3cdf538",
  "index": 4,
  "guid": "a08d2523-bf5a-4c5e-8f53-dd8cbba5c505",
  "isActive": false,
  "balance": "$2,631.16",
  "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 25,
  "eyeColor": "brown",
  "name": "Morrison Strong",
  "gender": "male",
  "company": "COMTOURS",
  "email": "morrisonstrong@comtours.com",
  "phone": "+1 (855) 574-2926",
  "address": "555 Bowery Street, Foxworth, Virginia, 4758",
  "about": "Sunt proident exercitation anim eiusmod amet deserunt dolor sunt. Ipsum dolor anim do ut quis dolore nisi eiusmod. Laborum dolor consequat irure consectetur deserunt aliquip occaecat esse sunt pariatur consectetur. Elit sint consequat fugiat sint ad fugiat mollit. Nostrud do non veniam nisi veniam fugiat dolor anim adipisicing.\r\n",
  "registered": "2014-07-30T06:36:56 +05:00",
  "latitude": 75.061884,
  "longitude": 93.11415,
  "tags": ["fugiat", "magna", "ea", "sunt", "minim", "excepteur", "nisi"],
  "friends": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Laurel Stanton"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Tricia Salinas"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Roxanne Day"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Cooley Jimenez"
  }],
  "greeting": "Hello, Morrison Strong! You have 7 unread messages.",
  "favoriteFruit": "apple"
}, {
  "_id": "555e4125970ae2387fab74ed",
  "index": 5,
  "guid": "990062ff-ab4f-4c3b-aad4-dbca366c22de",
  "isActive": true,
  "balance": "$1,527.76",
  "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 40,
  "eyeColor": "green",
  "name": "Buckner Kennedy",
  "gender": "male",
  "company": "SHEPARD",
  "email": "bucknerkennedy@shepard.com",
  "phone": "+1 (800) 524-3139",
  "address": "234 Kings Place, Darbydale, Wyoming, 8190",
  "about": "Cupidatat cupidatat commodo ut qui velit labore ea esse irure quis esse. Proident eu tempor amet proident amet consequat minim elit et tempor. Exercitation dolore aute nulla velit veniam qui eu. Tempor mollit elit magna cupidatat eu velit id consequat sint dolor qui. Nisi minim duis anim minim nulla in voluptate ea anim sit nostrud. Tempor commodo Lorem tempor aliqua est sint aliqua eu.\r\n",
  "registered": "2015-04-19T06:59:09 +05:00",
  "latitude": -89.386174,
  "longitude": 39.015288,
  "tags": ["sit", "sunt", "minim", "veniam", "cillum", "nisi", "enim"],
  "friends": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Cooley Jimenez"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mooney Hinton"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Stacy Ross"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Doyle Erickson"
  }],
  "greeting": "Hello, Buckner Kennedy! You have 8 unread messages.",
  "favoriteFruit": "banana"
}, {
  "_id": "555e4125ff554bdf2d6f080c",
  "index": 6,
  "guid": "2b5ad6ce-4a9b-4ec1-b869-cf0cac7c4d21",
  "isActive": false,
  "balance": "$1,453.63",
  "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 22,
  "eyeColor": "green",
  "name": "Doyle Erickson",
  "gender": "male",
  "company": "BLEENDOT",
  "email": "doyleerickson@bleendot.com",
  "phone": "+1 (976) 432-3644",
  "address": "182 Rockwell Place, Goldfield, Indiana, 8753",
  "about": "Veniam sunt amet amet dolor nostrud voluptate Lorem culpa est reprehenderit. Officia Lorem Lorem ut sit duis eu voluptate. Culpa aliqua sint in eiusmod. Duis incididunt sint velit ex ut excepteur. Deserunt nulla adipisicing minim minim cillum deserunt do tempor. Laboris nostrud cillum ea proident laboris do incididunt laborum. Eiusmod qui qui nulla velit do fugiat.\r\n",
  "registered": "2015-03-05T19:47:37 +06:00",
  "latitude": 72.253186,
  "longitude": -23.777045,
  "tags": ["dolore", "Lorem", "velit", "pariatur", "aliqua", "veniam"],
  "friends": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Torres Nguyen"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Francine Melendez"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Johnnie Berg"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Olga Newton"
  }],
  "greeting": "Hello, Doyle Erickson! You have 10 unread messages.",
  "favoriteFruit": "banana"
}, {
  "_id": "123e4125ff554bdf2d6f080c",
  "index": 7,
  "guid": "5c5ad6ce-4a9b-4ec1-b869-cf0cac7c4d21",
  "isActive": true,
  "balance": "$1,253.63",
  "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 22,
  "eyeColor": "green",
  "name": "Doris Smith",
  "gender": "transgender",
  "company": "BLEENDOT",
  "email": "dorissmith@bleendot.com",
  "phone": "+1 (976) 432-3644",
  "address": "182 Rockwell Place, Goldfield, Indiana, 8753",
  "about": "Veniam sunt amet amet dolor nostrud voluptate Lorem culpa est reprehenderit. Officia Lorem Lorem ut sit duis eu voluptate. Culpa aliqua sint in eiusmod. Duis incididunt sint velit ex ut excepteur. Deserunt nulla adipisicing minim minim cillum deserunt do tempor. Laboris nostrud cillum ea proident laboris do incididunt laborum. Eiusmod qui qui nulla velit do fugiat.\r\n",
  "registered": "2015-03-05T19:47:37 +06:00",
  "latitude": 72.253186,
  "longitude": -23.777045,
  "tags": ["dolore", "Lorem", "velit", "pariatur", "aliqua", "veniam", "aute"],
  "friends": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Buckner Kennedy"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Francine Melendez"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Johnnie Berg"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Olga Newton"
  }],
  "greeting": "Hello, Doris Smith! You have 10 unread messages.",
  "favoriteFruit": "banana"
}];



var topThreeTags = function(customers) {
  var output = [];
  var tagMap = {};
  customers.forEach(function(customer) {
    customer.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
      tagMap[tag] = (tagMap[tag] || 0) + 1;
    });
  });
  var sortedArr = Object.keys(tagMap).map(s => [s, tagMap[s]]).sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);
  output = sortedArr.slice(-3);
  return output;
};

console.log(topThreeTags(customers));
```

Comment: @KresimirPendic oh, thanks :) Share your version as well.

Comment: I'm trying to follow through your logic. So on the first iteration its best to just  to push the tags initially into an object, instead of an array? And secondly, what does the map in brackets provide reference to? I don't understand why you did Object. keys[map]. map. And also, what is the s in significance for? Is it the current value being passed to the inner function?

Comment: @Ashton I have added the explanation for each step, please have a look.

Comment: When I put this into my js console, it reguards map as undefined in the sorted array. Your answer is very detailed however, I am trying to understand the s to make it work with my code. I wanted to try to icorporate the prompt with my own function of map versus the native method  (which is what you are using in this prompt, correct?)

Comment: @Ashton can you please share a working snippet or a fiddle with me, so that I can look into it?

Comment: I don't know if this will work but I copied it in JS fiddle with the actual object https://jsfiddle.net/pcqb8u47/

Comment: I also have a question about the double useage of forEach. Wouldn't I use arr.map(function(item) to declare the map? Because the function I created with map has an each method within it

Comment: @Ashton I have added a demo as well.

Comment: I see the addition of console.log statements but no other information. Also, there is no demo running. Can you tell me what did you mean by the s is in car sortedArray? I don’t think that was formatted correctly with my map array so I’m trying to redo that statement

Comment: For the fiddle, please check the console logs in your browser's developer tools. Is the demo not working for you? Which browser are you testing it on? I am testing on Chrome. s is parameter to the arrow function callback handler of map.

Comment: Ok I see it now. I think putting the ES6 code in is throwing off my function, or it isn't incorporated right. I'm not that well versed in ES6 as of yet. I get that s is the parameter, I'm just asking what is s in referral of my function?

Comment: I figured out what it was; I’m only returning the array length. I need to actually return the actual tags. The way that they are stored, it’s like it’s being stored as a key/value pair, only in an array